# How to install Pyinstaller without cmd prompt?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner so there might be something wrong written, not a native speaker either...

I created a python script to edit some spreadsheets, and I'm wondering if there's a way to convert that to a .exe, so I don't have to open vscode every time. I did some search and find out that pyinstaller is a way to do it, but I couldn't figure out how to install it.

I'm using a corporate machine so I don't have access to the cmd prompt nor the terminal.

I can download the tar.bz2 file from anaconda.org, I don't know if that helps, but that's all I could do rn

Comment: If you have python installed can't you just associate python files with the python interpreter? What OS are you using?

Comment: Assuming Windows, can you right-click the file `>Open With >Choose Another App`, check `Always use this app to open .py files` and then select `Python`(NOT the one labeled "Launcher for Windows"). Doing that will allow you to simply double-click the file to run it.

Comment: Are you saying that there is not "terminal" option in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Pip package as you have said and follow the steps of this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/download-and-install-pip-latest-version/ to install the downloaded package.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would this work without `cmd prompt nor the terminal` as OP mentioned?

Comment: It wont work, i cant acess the cmd, soi wouldnt be able to change the path, like in the tutorial, i did some further research and saw that to create the .exe i would also need that acess, so im looking for other options rn

Comment: When I try to open the cmd it appears " cmd disabled by admin, press to continue", when i click the terminal on vscode the same thing happens

Comment: How do you write python code if you can't run or debug it?

Comment: If the cmd itself is disabled how can you even run any code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IDE called “PyCharm” installed on your machine, here’s what you can do:

#### The GUI Way

1. Go to the `File` Tab.
2. Click on `Settings`:

[image]

3. A dialog will popup. Click on `Project: <Your Project Name>`. Then click on `Python Interpreter` and then click on the `+` sign on the bottom of the dialog.
   [image]
4. Another dialog will popup. In the search bar at the top, search for the package  we want, in our case `pyinstaller`. Relevant results will appear. Click on the desired option.
5. Final Step. Just click `Install Package` at the bottom of the dialog and wait till it installs.[image]

Hooray! You have installed the package.

#### The Integrated Terminal Way

1. Open Pycharm and at the bottom, click on the `Terminal` option this will open up the integrated terminal.
2. Type  `pip install pyinstaller` and wait till it installs. You may have to use `pip3 install pyinstaller`. Wait till it installs.

Done!

#### Installing Another Terminal

If you don’t have PyCharm, you can choose this way. You can install some third-party terminal like `Git Bash`. You can download this terminal by [clicking here](https://git-scm.com).

After downloading, you can open `Git Bash` and try to run the commands that I mentioned in the above section. That’s it!

> Note that if `pip install pyinstaller` or `pip3 install pyinstaller` doesn’t work, you may need to add `python -m`  or `python3 -m`  at the start of the commands.

> Also note that the 2nd and 3rd options require pip and python to be in the system’s path.

Thank You!